# Highest eigenvalues/vectors of graph laplacian

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

In page 8 of the paper [Laplacian Eigenmaps for dimensionality reduction and Data Representation](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~mbelkin/papers/LEM_NC_03.pdf) it reads:

> Standard methods show that the solution is provided by the matrix of
>   eigenvectors corresponding to the lowest eigenvalues of the
>   generalized eigenvalue problem...

Can anyone explain why in this representation the "lowest eigenvalues" correspond to eigen-vectors which capture more information on the manifold? This is counter-intuitive to what happens in standard eigen-methods such as PCA.

I would also love an intuitive explanation to the isoperimetric/geometric properties of the **high** eigenvectors/eigenvalues, since these appear to be easier to compute for the problem I am facing (A large, sparse graph).

Any help is appreciated,
thanks!